# Redis as second level cache for entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, redis, ignite, second-level-cache

I'm using apache ignite as a second-level cache for entity framework version 6 for about two years but in my opinion, it is not a completely reliable cache for using in .net because it's starting a JVM machine inside iis thread pool and resets when iis recycles but it has a positive side and that is the ease of setup and control how to communicate with entity framework and for that, I'm trying to replace it with Redis cache.is there something like apache ignite nugget package that connects Redis and Entity framework automatically? or is there a better tool like ncache or something?

Comment: You don't need any library. Just write a decorator or interceptor for your query services and store query results in redis and read from that in next requests.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Ignite Thin client for .Net? It doesn’t have any overhead related to the JVM: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/thin-clients/dotnet-thin-client

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdi the problem is that the project is written with the apache ignite and there is no interceptor or some type of class or functions to handle the caching and therefore we need a huge amount of refactoring to do so I need some package or interceptor to easily manage the cache without changing the entire code

Comment: @dmagda thanks I will see if it fits my needs